# adobe form text field custom validation javascript to clear field if not valid

Tags: javascript, validation, adobe

I have an adobe form, with text fields that have custom validation scripts(javascript).  I would like the field to be cleared/reset if invalid text is entered.  Using event.rc = false works if the field was empty to begin with.  But I would like to have the text field cleared if someone typed valid text and then went back to change their entry, and then entered invalid text. I've tried using event.value == "" and this.resetForm(["FieldName"]) but neither are working for me.  (I'm using Adobe 9 Standard, so I can't use document level functions or anything like that.)  Here is the code. Any suggestions would be welcome. (This is my first posted question on SO). Thank you.

```
// only run when field not blank
if (event.value != "")
{
// RegExp for validation #########
var re = /^(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})$/
if(re.test(event.value) == false)
{
app.alert("Enter a 9-digit Social Security number with no spaces 
or special characters (e.g., 555555555). It will be converted to the format 
555-55-5555.")
this.resetForm(["SSN 1"]);    //also tried event.value == "" here
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my own question (in the Adobe Community Forum a users answer gave me the ah hah moment), and wanted to post it here for others searching for this same type of thing.  (I've seen others do it on SO and those self reply answers really have helped me in the past.)

the answer is: 
    `event.value = ""`
not: 
    `event.value == ""`

I am guessing this works because the value of "" is being assigned to the "event"/field value, rather than trying to make the event/field value equal "".

Comment: Thanks @daria877 but the text `event.value = ""` does not appear in your question. Did you mean to write `event.value  != ""` ? The `=` is an assignement operator and will assign the value of the right-hand side expression to the left-hand side variable or constant. The `==` and `!=` are operators that compare both sides and evaluate in a boolean `true` when equeal and `false` when not or vice versa in the case of `!=`. The comparison `== false` in your solution is not needed and could be replaced with `if( !re.test(event.value) )` which yields better understanable code.